# Aggregate results from for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, sentiment-analysis

I am doing sentiment analysis in python. After clearing up the tweets to use, I am stuck at getting the final sentiment score per tweet. I am getting the values but not able to aggregate the as one score per tweet. Here's the code

```
scores = {} # initialize an empty dictionary  
for line in sent_file:  
    term, score = line.split("\t") 
    scores[term] = int(score) # Convert the score to an integer.  



for line in tweet_file:  
       #convert the line from file into a json object  
    mystr = json.loads(line) 
    #check the language is english, if "lang" is among the keys  
    if 'lang' in mystr.keys() and mystr["lang"]=='en':  
            #if "text" is not among the keys, there's no tweet to read, skip it  
        if 'text' in mystr.keys(): 
            print mystr['text']
            resscore=[] 
            result = 0
            #split the tweet into a list of words  
            words = mystr["text"].split() 
            #print type(words)
            for word in words:  

                if word in scores:  
                    result = scores[word]
                    resscore.append(result)

                    print str(sum(resscore))


                else:  
                    result+=0
```

The output I am getting is like

```
If nothing is as you'd imagine it to be then you may as well start imaging some mad stuff like dragons playing chess on a…
 -3
 -1
```

But I want Those values in this case -3, -1 to be aggregated to give final score for that tweet i.e -4. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accumulate those values & print them after the loop ends:

```
# ...

finalScore = 0 # final score
for word in words:

    if word in scores:
        result = scores[word]
        resscore.append(result)

        finalScore += sum(resscore)

print(str(finalScore))

# ...
```